# Experience Guest User Profile Layout Assignment

Tags: community, profile, page-layout, experience-builder-page, experience-cloud

For the Experience Site that I am currently building, I want to show a preview of a several layouts which will encourage the guest to sign up.
This preview is supposed to be a limited set of fields of what's on the main layout.

I built a layout, find that when I go to assign the layout to the Guest User - the Guest User Profile is not visible.

I also know that to access to the Guest User Profile, I can get to it from the Experience Builder here:

[image]

However again, when I'm on this profile and click assign layouts from here:

[image]

Again, I'm just back at the regular layout assignment area - with no sign of the Guest Profile at all.

So my questions:

- Is it possible to assign a layout to the guest profile.
- What layout
  DOES it actually use (something definitely shows up, but I'm really
  not sure which one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using Lightning experience to view the "Page Layout Assignment".

I could reproduce the behavior you mentioned i.e., Page Layout Assignment doesn't show the Guest user's profile on my org too in LEX. However, when I switched to the classic view, I could find the Guest user's profile which in my case is named "Napili Site Profile" and edit the layout. That did the trick!

Click path: Switch to Classic > From Setup > All sites> click Builder next to "Napili Site" > Settings > General > select “Napili Site Profile” under Guest User Profile> View Assignment

Attaching screenshots:
Classic
[image: Classic]

Lightning Experience
[image: Lightning Experience]

Not sure if this is a bug. I will reach out to our concerned product team and update this thread as I have more inputs.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the case - from lightning, you cannot access the Guest Profile. From Classic, you can. How did you figure this out??

Comment: I saw a similar issue in the past based on which I checked in classic and LEX. 

Comment: this workaround is no longer required. Page Layout assignments are available via LEX Setup -> Sites -> `your site` -> Public Access Settings -> Object Settings -> `your object`